# Can I prevent typescript from defining a generic as a literal number

Tags: typescript, types, casting, type-conversion, typeerror

I am trying to create a class that takes both `number` (for hex) and a `number[]` (for rgb) as a `color` option and to also be referenced in a getter/setter. Currently the array works fine, however when using hex values it forces the generic to be a literal number, for example `0xff00ff` is being defined as `16711935` instead of `number`.

This creates an issue where it cannot be redefined, as setting `color` to `0xff0000` created the following TS error

`Type '16711680' is not assignable to type '16711935'`

A code example can be found on this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EoDEySZPkzilUKG5njImwSigAArE8fQAA3Y0zTGw-MoGY2kaGABg11uYNtjgDRqBYBziEhVcOh9BssCKciiJI6AdGgE9OBC8oGlfbRwvAaA4AMsAbEaOA2HUKBhXrJshK6djFVMIA)

I have forced the cast to the class, and it solves the issue (`new MyClass<number>({...})`). However if there is a way to prevent forced literals automatically, that would be preferable against having to make the user cast the type directly during the class instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option that comes to my mind would be to store the *whole* `MyClassOptions` as `T` and not just the type of `color`.

```
class MyClass<T extends MyClassOptions<ColorLike>> {
    static readonly DEFAULT_OPTIONS: MyClassOptions<number> = { color: 0x000000 };

    private _realColor!: T["color"];

    constructor(options: T) {
        options = { ...MyClass.DEFAULT_OPTIONS as T, ...options };
    }

    get color(): T["color"] { return this._realColor; }
    set color(value: T["color"]) { this._realColor = value; }
}

const a = new MyClass({ color: [1, 0, 1] });
//    ^? const a: MyClass<{ color: number[]; }>
a.color = [1, 0, 0]

const b = new MyClass({ color: 0xff00ff });
//    ^? const b: MyClass<{ color: number; }>
b.color = 0xff0000
```

Since the supplied value of `color` is nested inside the generic type, TypeScript will not infer the literal type.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: I have accepted your helpful answer, but I will also note that the `any` type can be set to `ColorLike` in this instance

Comment: @AshCook - good observation! The `any` type would have allowed passing strings and other non-allowed types. I did not properly think this through :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are submitting an object without defining type in it's content, so it become "immutable" if you will.

For example, if you specify a type of the `color` in that object it will work fine:

```
const b = new MyClass({ color: 0xff00ff as number});
```

Comment: The problem with this is I still have to cast, which is something I'd rather avoid, thank you for your insight regardless.